# The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library - looking in wrong DLL

Tags: c++, dll

When building for a specific configuration, my program seems to be looking for specific functions in the wrong DLL. These functions are defined in different DLLs, and used in completely separate sections of the code, and the error is always referring to the same DLL (libvlc.dll). If I build in a different configuration or disable anything using libvlc.dll, everything works. Everything builds without errors or warnings, but the program will crash before the first line is hit when using Debug -> Step Into

```
The procedure entry point ReportFault could not be located in the dynamic link library libvlc.dll
The procedure entry point curl_easy_setopt could not be located in the dynamic link library libvlc.dll
The procedure entry point ogg_stream_packetin could not be located in the dynamic link library libvlc.dll
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by vlc being built with `/OPT:NOREF` while my project was using `/OPT:REF` https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=98097