# Procedure entry point couldn't be located in the DLL

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, ffmpeg

I am trying to launch release build(32bit) of my application in VS2012.On the start-up I am getting this error:

> "Entry Point Not found" The procedure entry point
>   __glewMatrixTranslatefEXT could not be located in the dynamic link library avcodec-55.dll.

Now, I am using OpenGL GLEW extension loader lib and FFMPEG libs in my software,and I can't get why the error asks for __glewMatrixTranslatefEXT ,which is OpenGL method defined in GLEW , to be present in avcodec-55.dll which is FFMPEG lib.Btw, it doesn't happen in debug build and not on Linux.

**UPDATE:**

I finally solved it based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867607/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-loo?rq=1) post ,so setting /OPT:NOREF in linker optimzation settings menu removed that error.It still would be nice to get an explanation why it happened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library - looking in wrong DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867607/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-loo)