# ffmpeg: Failed to call av_register_all

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got an Windows 7 application that is using ffmpeg to decode video frames.

It is using an older version of ffmpeg (not sure exactly which one) but it is working ok, except some decoding errors when calling avcodec_decode_video2 from increasing number of threads.

So I decided to upgrade the ffmpeg to a newer build and got 2.1.1 (latest).
I got it off http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

I managed to compile the application using the new include/libs.

However, when I run the application it throws an exception that a function was not found during dll loading. 
I traced that to av_register_all() which is inside avformat.lib and avformat-55.dll.

It looks like the definition of this function in tha ffmpeg library was changed over the versions. It no longer points to avformat-55.dll (none that I was able to find using dumpbin).

So what is the best way to call this function from a C++ dll?

Currently, in my include file I have this:

```
extern "C" 
{
#include "libavutil\dict.h"
#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat\avformat.h"

};

#pragma comment(lib,"avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"avutil.lib")
```

Many thanks!

Ofer

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be a simple linker option /OPT:NOREF, according to this post:

[The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library - looking in wrong DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867607/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-loo?rq=1)