# The procedure entry point could not be located in dynamic link library Qt5Cored.dll

Tags: visual-studio, qt, dll, linker

[image: The procedure entry point could ?registerNormalizedType not be located in dynamic link library Qt5Cored.dll]

I just built the project that I'm supposed to fix. I double checked that correct DLLs are loaded - the project uses Qt 5.3.0, and the dlls are loaded from 5.3.0 directory. I am not sure where is the problem. Is my project using incorrect Qt headers? Or is the DLL build incorrectly?

I'm building in Debug with Visual Studio 2017. The DLLs are also built with visual studio. I tried Vidual Studio 2010 instead, since it's 2010 project, but the error was the same.

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426326/qt-deployment-the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located

Comment: Or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524620/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-dynamic-link-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was following:

One of the sub-projects was accidentally configured to use Qt 5.6.1, whereas the rest of the solution used 5.3.0. I found out by opening the result binary in dependency walker.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in release or debug mode? QtCoded.dll is related to debug profile.

Another explanation could be how your Qt was built.
If I remember correctly Qt was built with msvc2015 so you have to use msvc2015 to build your exe with Visual Studio and it is not possible to use a msvc version before or after that.
Please remeber that you can't use the Qt framework built with mingw with msvc.

In other words I suggest you to check which version of msvc are you using with Visual Studio and which version of Qt framework.

Regards.

Comment: This is not an answer. Requests for more information should be made in the comments section. Only complete answers should be posted as answer. I see you do not have enough rep to post comments yet, but it doesn't excuse you from those rules. You should read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Please use answer box to answer the question not asking questions.

Comment: I'm building in Debug with Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with QT 4.

The solution was found on this post: [The procedure entry point could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854074/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-found)

> I ran into the same problem, and in my case, this was due to the fact that I had two versions of the same library installed on my computer.

> In the end, the problem was that I was linking my program against the new LIB file while my PATH was pointing to the old DLL. When the library version number is not included in the LIB or DLL file names, it is very easy to mix the versions.

I my case I was using a `QtCored4.dll` and others from an older version of QT. The solution was copy the DLLs directly from my QT installation directory which was used to build the application (as it was set by my `QTDIR` environment variable):  `C:\Qt\4.8.7\bin` to my application directory.